# concat all rows in a column where another column matches/equals something in sqlite

Tags: c++, sqlite, while-loop, concatenation

I am trying to properly output all of the rows in the names column where the IP column is the same as the client IP in C++. This is working properly, however the output is each name on a newline. I want to somehow use concatstring or some other method to bring all of the names onto the same line. When I use the method I commented out in the code, it doesn't work properly because it's in the while loop - it outputs like such:

```
name
name, name2
name, name2, name3
```

which is undesired. if I move stuff out of the while loop it either is not in the scope, or will crash with segmentation fault because it can't access the data. If i use a bool to check and only output once inside the while loop, only the first name from the list will be displayed. I just want all of the names to display on the same line, like such:

```
name, name2, name3
```

Here is a snipet from the code below:

```
while ((rc = sqlite3_step(stmt3)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                 std::string names(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt3, 0)));
                 out(ECHO_SERV, names.c_str());
                 /*char msg[MAXTRANS];
                 string buf;
                 formatstring(msg)("%s, ", names.c_str());
                 concatstring(buf, msg, MAXTRANS);
                 out(ECHO_SERV, buf);*/
             }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Here is the full code:

```
static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<argc; i++){
            printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
        }
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
    }
    
    void savestats(clientinfo *ci)
    {
        sqlite3 *db;
        char *zErrMsg = 0;
        int  rc;
        const char *sql;
        bool name_match, ip_match;
        const char* player_database_names;
        const char* player_database_ips;
        char *p_name = ci->name;
        char *p_ip = ci->ip;
        
        //Open database
        rc = sqlite3_open("playerinfo.db", &db);
        if( rc ){
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
            exit(0);
        }else{
            fprintf(stdout, "Opened database successfully\n");
        }
        //Handle errors
        if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
            fprintf(stderr, "SQL Database Error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
            sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
        //Fetch names from database for comparison
        }else{
            //name match
            sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
            defformatstring(sqlstrprep)("SELECT NAME FROM PLAYERINFO");
            rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sqlstrprep, -1, &stmt, NULL);
            
            while ((rc = sqlite3_step(stmt)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                //int id = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
                player_database_names = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0));
                if(!strcmp(player_database_names, p_name)) name_match = true;
                else name_match = false;
            }
            //ip match (doesn't work)
            sqlite3_stmt *stmt2;
               defformatstring(sqlstrprep2)("SELECT IP FROM PLAYERINFO");
            rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sqlstrprep2, -1, &stmt2, NULL);
            
            while ((rc = sqlite3_step(stmt2)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                int id = sqlite3_column_int(stmt2, 6);
                player_database_ips = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt2, id));
                //if(!strcmp(player_database_ips, p_ip)) ip_match = true; //seg fault EXC_BAD_ACCESS
                if(player_database_ips == p_ip) ip_match = true;
                else ip_match = false;
            }
        }
        
        //Create the table if it doesn't exist
        sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PLAYERINFO("    \
        "NAME                       TEXT    NOT NULL,"    \
        "FRAGS                       INT    NOT NULL,"    \
        "DEATHS                      INT    NOT NULL,"    \
        "FLAGS                       INT    NOT NULL,"    \
        "PASSES                      INT    NOT NULL,"    \
        "IP                         TEXT    NOT NULL,"    \
        "ACCURACY          DECIMAL(4, 2)    NOT NULL,"    \
        "KPD               DECIMAL(4, 2)    NOT NULL);";
        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
        if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
            fprintf(stderr, "SQLITE3 ERROR @ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS: %s\n", zErrMsg);
            sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
        }else{
            if(!name_match) fprintf(stdout, "No previous record found under that name\n");
            else fprintf(stdout, "Found name and IP already, updating record instead\n");
        }
        
        char sqlINSERT[256];
        char sqlUPDATE[1000];
        int p_frags = ci->state.frags;
        int p_deaths = ci->state.deaths;
        int p_flags = ci->state.flags;
        int p_passes = ci->state.passes;
        int p_acc = (ci->state.damage*100)/max(ci->state.shotdamage, 1);
        int p_kpd = (ci->state.frags)/max(ci->state.deaths, 1);
        
        //name and ip are different
        if(!name_match) {
            sprintf(sqlINSERT, "INSERT INTO PLAYERINFO( NAME,FRAGS,DEATHS,FLAGS,PASSES,IP,ACCURACY,KPD ) VALUES ('%s', %d, %d, %d, %d, '%s', %d, %d)",p_name,p_frags,p_deaths,p_flags,p_passes,p_ip,p_acc,p_kpd);
            rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sqlINSERT, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
        }
        //name is the same, update the database if the new information is > than db_info
        else if(name_match)  {
            sprintf(sqlUPDATE,
            "UPDATE PLAYERINFO SET FRAGS = %d+(SELECT FRAGS FROM PLAYERINFO) WHERE NAME = '%s';"     \
            "UPDATE PLAYERINFO SET DEATHS = %d+(SELECT DEATHS FROM PLAYERINFO) WHERE NAME = '%s';"   \
            "UPDATE PLAYERINFO SET FLAGS = %d+(SELECT FLAGS FROM PLAYERINFO) WHERE NAME = '%s';"     \
            "UPDATE PLAYERINFO SET PASSES = %d+(SELECT PASSES FROM PLAYERINFO) WHERE NAME = '%s';"   \
            "UPDATE PLAYERINFO SET ACCURACY = %d+(SELECT PASSES FROM PLAYERINFO) WHERE NAME = '%s';" \
            "UPDATE PLAYERINFO SET KPD = %d+(SELECT PASSES FROM PLAYERINFO) WHERE NAME = '%s';",
            ci->state.frags, ci->name, ci->state.deaths, ci->name, ci->state.flags, ci->name, ci->state.passes, ci->name, p_acc, ci->name, p_kpd, ci->name);
            rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sqlUPDATE, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
        }
        if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
            fprintf(stderr, "SQLITE3 ERROR @ INSERT & UPDATE: %s\n", zErrMsg);
            sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
        }else{
            fprintf(stdout, "Playerinfo modified\n");
        }
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }
    
    void getstats(clientinfo *ci)
    {
        sqlite3 *db;
        char *zErrMsg = 0;
        int rc;
        char *sql;
        const char* data = "Callback function called";
        
        /* Open database */
        rc = sqlite3_open("playerinfo.db", &db);
        if( rc ){
            fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
            exit(0);
        }
        
        //rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);
        if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
            fprintf(stderr, "SQL Database Error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
            sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
        }else{
            sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
            //defformatstring(sqlstrprep)("SELECT * FROM PLAYERINFO WHERE NAME GLOB '%s*';", ci->name);
           defformatstring(sqlstrprep)("SELECT NAME,FRAGS,DEATHS,FLAGS FROM PLAYERINFO WHERE NAME == '%s';", ci->name);
            rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sqlstrprep, -1, &stmt, NULL);
            
            bool necho = false;
            while ((rc = sqlite3_step(stmt)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                //int id = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
                const char* name = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0));
                const char* frags = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1));
                const char* deaths = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2));
                const char* flags = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 3));
                if(!necho) {
                    out(ECHO_SERV, "Name: \f2%s \f7Frags: \f0%s \f7Deaths: \f3%s \f7Flags: \f5%s", name,frags,deaths,flags);
                    out(ECHO_CONSOLE, "Name: %s, Frags: %s, Deaths: %s, Flags: %s", name,frags,deaths,flags);
                    necho = true;
                }
            }

            //returns names
            sqlite3_stmt *stmt3;
            defformatstring(sqlstrprep3)("SELECT NAME FROM PLAYERINFO WHERE IP == '%s';", ci->ip);
             rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sqlstrprep3, -1, &stmt3, NULL);
             
             while ((rc = sqlite3_step(stmt3)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                 std::string names(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt3, 0)));
                 out(ECHO_SERV, names.c_str());
                 /*char msg[MAXTRANS];
                 string buf;
                 formatstring(msg)("%s, ", names.c_str());
                 concatstring(buf, msg, MAXTRANS);
                 out(ECHO_SERV, buf);*/
             }
        }
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }
```

Comment: Please pick *one* language as string concatenation could (and should) be handled differently in the two very different languages you tagged.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude c++. The mod is a mix of c and c++.

Comment: Why in the world are you doing all that sprintf stuff instead of proper binding of values to parameters in prepared statements?

Comment: @Shawn some of the calls use sprintf and others are prepared, I will clean it up later. Also I have to move the database init to when the server starts as well. Right now i'm just trying to make sure it functions properly, which it does, except all of the names are on new lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, this gets all of the rows from column NAME where IP = our client IP.

```
void QServ::getnames(clientinfo *ci) {
        if(enable_sqlite_db) {
            sqlite3_stmt *stmt3;
            sqlite3 *db;
            int rc;
            rc = sqlite3_open("playerinfo.db", &db);
            defformatstring(sqlstrprep3)("SELECT group_concat(NAME, ', ') FROM PLAYERINFO WHERE IP == '%s';", ci->ip);
            rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sqlstrprep3, -1, &stmt3, NULL);
            while ((rc = sqlite3_step(stmt3)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                std::string names(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt3, 0)));
                defformatstring(nmsg)("Names from IP \f2%s\f7: %s", ci->ip, names.c_str());
                out(ECHO_SERV, nmsg);
            }
            sqlite3_close(db);
        }
    }
```